# Nodejs ..express..router . 1 router to get 2 collection data . I AM A BEGINEER

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 collections . Userlist & Roomlist. I tried to get collection from userlist using

```
 var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('usercollection');
collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
    res.render('userlist', {
        "userlist" : docs
    });
});
```

it is working perfectly . But when i replicate the same code for roomlist it is NOT WORKING.

```
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('roomlist');
collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
    res.render("roomlist",{
        "roomname" : docs
    });
});
```

Please help me know the difference and how to resolve this

Comment: Can you check req.db is set? using console.log.

Comment: ugh. i am not aware of it . if i used console.log it is not working properly

Comment: simply use console.log(req.db).

Comment: @naeplus:  I tried it but it is not so working                                                                                   var db = req.db;
        console.log(db);

Comment: not working means? can't you see output in terminal?

Comment: @naeplus : yes. It is not showing in my console

Comment: @neaplus: You have any wild guess why it is not working and can you help me to solve this one ??